# How do I get the size of all windows on the screen in windows 7?

Tags: windows

I am trying to write a program that gets the windows that are displayed on the screen. Something like screen.getActiveWindow().size would be cool, but it only addresses the active window.

I am looking for the sizes of all windows on the screen, as well as event information when they are resized, cover each other up.

Am I just daydreaming or is there a way to get this information on windows?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [EnumWindow Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx) go get the hwnd of each window then user EnumChildWindow to get the child windows and finally get [windowinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633516%28VS.85%29.aspx) the clr doesn't have all of the necessary function to do low level window manipulation unless its been added in 4.0 and I haven't noticed.